# Determining matrix that minimizes linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am looking for some guidance or a point in the right direction as to how to solve a problem.

I have an objective function $O:\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is dependent on a set of known and unknown matrices. I want to find the set of all unknown matrices that minimizes the objective function and that are of a certain form.

For instance, although trivial, let $ O = tr(AX) $, where $A$ and $X$ represent the known and unknown matrices respectively. I want to find the $X$ that minimizes $O$ but also has the form $X_{i,j} = H(j-a_{i})*H(b_{i} - j)$ where H(x) is the heaviside function and so each row can only have the form (for example) $[1 0 0 ], [0 1 0], [0 0 1], [1 1 0], [0 1 1], [1 1 1] $

Comment: What are $a_i$ and $b_i$?  Are they given in advance?

Comment: Hello @littleO, $a_i$ and $b_i$ are not known prior but an initial guess of them could be given. As to what they are; in the specific problem I would solve, X would represent the exposed and blocked regions (represented by 0s and 1) of a collimation system whereby each row has two independent leaves for blocking out the beam (e.g. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multileaf_collimator) ). Therefore $a_I$ and $b_i$ would represent the left and right positions of the ith row's leaves.

Comment: Ah.  One observation is that your optimization problem seems to separate into independent subproblems, one subproblem for each row of $X$.  Tell me if this is correct: for each row of $X$, we have to decide two numbers: $a_i$ and $b_i$.  Both are integers from $0$ to $n$, and $a_i \leq b_i$.  Once you determine $a_i$ and $b_i$ for each row, then $X$ is fully determined.  You could potentially find $a_i$ and $b_i$ for each row by brute force search.  Do you think that's too slow?

Comment: Thanks for the input again @littleO you are correct also. Brute force searches were what I was attempting to avoid, my hope was that I was overlooking or unaware of a method for finding a subset of the solution that met the additional criteria. Thanks for pointing out the independent subproblems